# Passing model data to urlpatterns in Django's urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to write a generic **urlpatterns** entry in *urls.py* that would replace hardcoded entries, as below:

```
path('apple/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/apple/abc/'), name='apple_redirect'),
path('orange/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/orange/def/'), name='orange_redirect'),
path('banana/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/banana/ghi/'), name='banana_redirect'),
```

The model called **fruits** holds the following data:

```
    name = 'apple'
    url = 'apple/abc/'

    name = 'orange'
    url = '/orange/def/'

    name = 'banana'
    url = '/banana/ghi/'
```

I would like to avoid the need for manual addition of another path in case new entry in **fruits** model is added.

Comment: Yes having parameters in URLs of the normal thing to do and is well described in the tutorial and docs. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: well, I know how to capture URL parameters, say apple, but I do not know how to check if given parameter exists in fruits model, and if it does how to pull corresponding apple/abc and place it n the RedirectView.as_view(). I just started with django, hence potentially obvious things are not that clear yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch url param and pass it to your view like this

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404

def fruit_redirect_view(request, url_path):
    fruit = get_object_or_404(Fruit, name=url_path)
    return redirect(fruit.url)
```

So if fruit with such name exists, request will be redirected to fruit's url, otherwise 404 error will be raised

Comment: Clear and easy to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `RedirectView`, you can subclass it and override [`get_redirect_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.get_redirect_url).

```
class FruitRedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self):
        fruit = get_object_or_404(Fruit, name=self.kwargs['fruit'])
        return fruit.url
```

Then replace your individual fruit URL patterns with:

```
path('<slug:fruit>/', FruitRedirectView.as_view(), name='fruit_redirect'),
```

Note you don't need to use `RedirectView` here. Alex C's view is easier to understand, especially if you're not familiar with Django's generic views.

Note that once you have added the `<slug:fruit>/`, the view will raise a 404 error for any fruits that are not in the database. This is slightly different than when you had `apple/` and `orange/` in your URL patterns - in that case, Django might be able to match a pattern further down your list of URL patterns.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.